# Why can't my makefile invoke the Windows 10 cmd shell?

Tags: cmd, makefile

With my new Windows 10 workstation, I can't build any projects since for some reason, `make` can't invoke `cmd`. The command is normally used to check for version numbers in directories etc. and leads to cancellation of the build process.

See here some snippets from the makefile in question:

```
# windows cmd shell
SHELL=$(SYSTEMROOT)/System32/cmd
CC=c:/path/to/compiler
# ...
COMPILER_VALID=FALSE
ifeq ($(DESIRED_VERSION),$(shell "$(CC)"))
    COMPILER_VALID=TRUE
endif
ifneq ($(COMPILER_VALID),TRUE)
    $(error incorrect compiler version)
endif
# ...
```

This used to work on my old computer; it still works as intended for all my colleagues. However, when I run `make`on my current machine, it produces this output:

```
PS C:\Users\Buerger\Project> make release
make: C:Windows/System32/cmd: Command not found
build\makefile.mak:123: *** incorrect compiler version.  Stop.
```

`cmd.exe`is present at C:\Windows\System32\ , and C:\path\to\compiler is a valid directory on my machine. As far as I'm aware, all required development tools are installed. What am I missing here, what could be the reason why I can't build what everyone else can?

---

EDIT addressing comment: Changing the makefile isn't an option. The output of `make --version` and the value of `SYSTEMROOT` is

```
> make --version 
GNU Make 3.81                                                                                                          Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
This program built for i686-pc-cygwin         

> echo %SYSTEMROOT%
C:\Windows
```

Comment: I would drop this `SHELL` setting since it's the default anyway. Please also share output of `make --version`, since there are many different variants of Make for Windows.

Comment: hi raspy, I added that information. Can't drop the SHELL, though.

Comment: I see a missing "/" after "C:" in make: C:Windows/System32/cmd: Command not found

Comment: Agreed: the missing `/` is definitely a problem. Maybe your `SYSTEMROOT` variable is set incorrectly: you don't show us where the value for that variable comes from.  If it comes from the environment check that your environment variables are set properly.

Comment: SYSTEMROOT isn't defined in the makefile, it comes from the environment. `echo %SYSTEMROOT%` yields `C:\Windows` , which seems to be in line with my colleagues' machines.

Comment: If using `cmd`-based syntax in Makefile, why use Cygwin make instead of native one?

Comment: @raspy , I don't know, that decision wasn't mine to make.

Comment: It appears that the version of `make` you are now using is performing variable expansion differently than the one you were using on your old system.  Rather than taking the backslash in the value of environment variable `SYSTEMROOT` as a literal character, it is interpreting it as an escape character.  Perhaps this is specific to how it uses the `SHELL` variable.  If you cannot change the makefile, then your most likely solution is to make sure to use the same version of `make` that worked for you in your old environment.

Comment: If anyone else can build with this Makefile, check their environment, most notably `make --version`. This `SYSTEMROOT` expansion must be working differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with this Cygwin version of make.

Version 3.81 with Cygwin seems to wrongly expand backslashes in this SHELL variable. This results in a path like `C:Windows/system32/cmd`.

Example:

```
PS C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Downloads> Get-Content .\Makefile
$(info $(SYSTEMROOT))

SHELL=$(SYSTEMROOT)/system32/cmd

$(info $(shell ver))

PS C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Downloads> C:\cygwin\bin\make.exe
C:\Windows
make: C:Windows/system32/cmd: Command not found

make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

This IS a valid path, it's a relative path against current working directory in drive C:, which means that in order for it to work would be to set up your current working directory of drive C: to root drive and call your `Makefile` with full path (or from other drive). Alternatively you could change your `SHELL` setting to just read `cmd.exe` (without path) so that it will be located automatically through `PATH`.

But even in those cases, on a modern Windows you will hit another issue - a hanging `cmd.exe` session, e.g.:

```
PS C:\> C:\cygwin\bin\make.exe -f C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Downloads\Makefile -dr
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i686-pc-cygwin
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Downloads\Makefile'...
C:\Windows
<< hanging indefinitely >>
```

Note that it does not complain about shell, in fact it was located and run, but with a `-c` switch instead of `/c`, causing `cmd.exe` to not exit after the command (so `make` will hang waiting). Examine:

```
PS C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount> (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter { Name = 'cmd.exe' }).CommandLine
C:Windows\system32\cmd.exe -c ver
```

If you try to run it on your own from PowerShell, you will see that it will end up in `cmd` and not return to PS:

```
PS C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount> cmd -c ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount>exit    <--- Note command prompt change
PS C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount>
```

as opposed to what it should be:

```
PS C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount> cmd /c ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836]
PS C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount>
```

You might replace `-c` with `/C` by using `.SHELLFLAGS`, but this was introduced in make 3.82.

Bottom line: I believe you should be using a newer version of `make`. My first choice, since you use `cmd`-based syntax anyway, would be a native build of make for Windows (not Cygwin, not MinGW). If you stick to Cygwin, you should install the latest version (current Cygwin `make` is 4.3 and it does not have those problems). Note that version you attempt to use was released in 2006 and many improvements (including Windows-based behavior) have been implemented since then.

Comment: thanks, this indeed was the cause of the issue! My options regarding make builds are limited, but switching to MinGW did the trick.